# UISPlitViewController popover button missing

Tags: objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

I am trying to replace the current view with a SplitViewController programatically. This is my code.

```
ProjectNavigationController *projectNavPanel = [[ProjectNavigationController alloc] init];
[projectNavPanel setProjectIndex:[indexPath row]];
[projectNavPanel setKuluId:[[[[[appDelegate userSettingsDictionary] objectForKey:@"Projects"] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:@"Kulu Id"] intValue]];

ProjectDetailController *projectDetailPanel = [[ProjectDetailController alloc] init];
[projectDetailPanel setProjectIndex:[indexPath row]];
ProjectSplitViewController *splitRootController = [[ProjectSplitViewController alloc] init];

[splitRootController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:projectNavPanel, projectDetailPanel, nil]];

[[self view] removeFromSuperview];
[[appDelegate window] setRootViewController:splitRootController];
```

This is almost working fine, with one exception.  When the split view controller is loaded and in portrait mode, the navigation view hides - as expected - but the detail view has no toolbar with a button to show the navigation in a popover view. From my research, i understood this was the default behaviour.  Am I missing something? There is very little in the detailViewController so I have not included the code here, but if it helps, let me know.

Comment: Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There are some things missing in your code;

First, to have the navigationbar to add the button to, you have to have a `UINavigationController` in between your `UISplitViewController` and your `ProjectDetailController`.

Second, you have to setup a UISplitViewControllerDelegate and use the delegate methods to add the button:

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc
{   
    [[projectDetailPanel navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem animated:YES];
}

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
{
    [[projectDetailPanel navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];
}
```

And third, don't forget to set the title to your `ProjectNavigationController`, or set a title manually to the `barButtonItem` in the `splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController` method you just implemented.